# vb.net moving panels backwards and forwards of eachother

Tags: vb.net, panel, move

I have been trying to workout how I can move overlapping panels forward or backward from oneanother but with no success I thought the following code would work but it hasn't had any visible effect.

```
    Private Sub Panel2_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Panel2.Click
    Me.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

Also tried

```
    Private Sub Panel3_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Panel3.Click
    Me.Activate()
End Sub
```

And

```
    Private Sub Panel3_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Panel3.Click
    Me.TopMost = True
End Sub
```

also failing?

Answer (score 0):

In your actual context I think `Me` refers to the form. Instead os using `Me`, try to change your code to the specific panel you want to change:

```
Panel1.BringToFront()
```

If you want, alternatively, you can use the `sender` variable of the event to take the panel:

```
Private Sub Panel3_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
Handles Panel1.Click, Panel2.Click, Panel3.Click
    Dim auxPanel As Panel = CType(sender, Panel)
    auxPanel.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

By the way, the correct method to rearrange the controls to overlap between them is `.BringToFront()` and `.SendToBack()`. `.TopMost` and `.Activate` have different uses. See the MSDN Documentation about it to learn their respective function.

Comment: `DirectCast(sender, Panel)` might be better in this case(if only for better readability since you don't have to convert types, just casting)